# What's the coolest way to prove that $p^k - 1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ where p is a prime not equal to 3, and k is an even positive integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The proof I immediately thought of was based on the following difference of squares:

$p^k - 1 = (p^{\frac{k}{2}} + 1)(p^{\frac{k}{2}} - 1)$

Since $p^{\frac{k}{2}} - 1$, $p^{\frac{k}{2}}$, and $p^{\frac{k}{2}} + 1$ are three consecutive integers, one of them must be divisible by 3. We know that $p^{\frac{k}{2}}$ isn't divisible by 3 because $p \neq 3$, so it must be one of the other two. Since $p^k - 1$ is a product of the other two, then it must be divisible by 3.

What's the coolest or most elegant way you can think of to prove this?

Comment: It's completely irrelevant that $p$ is a prime; the only relevant fact is that it is not divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 5):

Using congruences: if $p$ is a prime not equal to $3$, it is congruent to $\pm1\mod 3$, so $p^2\equiv 1\mod 3$, whence
$$p^k-1=\bigl(p^2\bigr)^{\tfrac k2}-1\equiv 1-1=0\mod 3.$$

For the same reason, you easily see that if $k$ is odd, $p^k\equiv p\mod 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Use induction. If $k =2$, then $p^k-1=p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$. Clearly 3 divides $(p-1)(p+1)$ since 3 doesn't divide $p$.  Now suppose $3$ divides $p^k-1$ for $k=2n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Then,
 $p^{2(n+1)}-1=p^{2n}p^2-1=p^{2n}p^2-p^2+p^2-1=p^2(p^{2n}-1)+(p^2-1).$ But by inductive hypothesis $3$ divides $p^{2n}-1$ and as seen before 3 divides $p^2-1$.

Hence 3 divides $p^{2(n+1)}$. Therefore 3 divides $p^k-1$ for even positive  integer $k.$